# ZF2 sharing data between event handlers (attach)

Tags: php, events, zend-framework2

I'm trying to share data between event attachments in zf2.

to be exact, im attaching to missingTranslation which is a part zf2 translator.
I need to catch some data in the missingTranslation and then at the end of execution, Dispatch or Finish i am going to do some validation on the data and then if everything is validated, i'm going to save it.

```
attach('missingTranslation', function ($e){
    // some kind of storage with $e->getParam('message');
});

attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, function (){
    // some validation, checks and mangling 
    file_put_content({the_storage});
});
```

I have been looking into caching the data, but using xcache or apc requires special extension, that the server does not have.

So my question is how do i do this?

Comment: you could set the value on a singleton and retrieve it from the storage manager, but introducing global state isn't usually my favorite thing

Comment: Yes globals is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass the information along with the Event passed in to the callback. like this

```
$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,function (MvcEvent $e) {
    $e->setParam('test', 10);
}, 200);

$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,function (MvcEvent $e) {
   var_dump($e->getParam('test'));
}, 100);
```

This would output 10 on the var_dump

Comment: Thanks that helped me find the problem. you are using 2 DISPATCH events but DISPATCH is before missingTranslation, thats why it didn't work for me (I posted my personal result for others to see)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the wait.

It took me some time to notice that of course, the event DISPATCH actually runs before event missingTranslation.

so instead of DISPATCH I'm using FINISH

```
$this->translatorEventManager->attach('missingTranslation',function ($e) use (&$storage)
    {
        if ($this->config['string_length'] <= strlen($e->getParam('message'))
            || $this->config['string_length'] == -1
        ) {
            $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
            $ref = str_replace($this->config['zf_base_path'],
                    '',
                    $backtrace[10]['file']
                )
                . ':' . $backtrace[10]['line'];
            $storage[$e->getParam('locale')][] = array(
                'message_id'     => $e->getParam('message'),
                'message_string' => '',
                'domain'         => $e->getParam('domain'),
                'reference'      => $ref,
            );
        } else {
            // LOAD FROM DATABASE
        }

    });
    $this->appEventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH, function($e) use ($translator, &$storage) {
        $translator
            ->addTranslations($storage)
            ->save();
    });
```

some of you might say this is a very bad way to do it, because debug_backtract() is known to eat a lot of time. and it will clutter the modules onBootstrap a lot.

To get this running well, the system is running an external curl command in the background, and then it runs the same page, but with the param "thread".
so even if it would take 1min to run the entire module, the user would never notice it.